# Simple QrCode. generate many qr code using laravel

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I would like to generate many QR code using 
"Simple QrCode" 
https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode

I can make one QR code like this

```
{!! QrCode::size(100)->generate('http://www.mywebsite.com') !!}
```

but how do I make alot.

I'm beginer this code looks not good. sorry.
I can make loop but loop numbers doesn't work.

```
<table border="1">
<?php

for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {

    $url = "http://localhost/acex/1.php?g=". $i;
    $qr = '{!! QrCode::size(100)->generate(' . $url .') !!}';


    echo "<a href=\"http://localhost/acex/1.php?g=". $i . "\">link </a>";
    echo"<br>";
?>

<tr>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo "<a href=\"http://localhost/acex/1.php?g=". $i . "\">link </a>";
            ?>

        </td>   

        <td>
             <?php
            echo $qr;
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
            echo $url;
            ?>

        </td>


</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: You re-assign the value of `$qr` each time through the loop, then only consume that value once you break out of the loop, meaning you will only ever see the last value assigned.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for comment. Could you teach me how to write code at laravel please? I've been trying but I can't fill in php?g=1 php?g=2 php?g=3 ...

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code on your controller?

Comment: Hi Asur. I didn't use Controller when I generate QR code. I just install this stuff and typed {!! QrCode::size(100)->generate(' . $url .') !!}' that's it.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate many"?

Comment: Hi Nico. Sorry for my English. I mean I would like to make 100 QR code images  using php loop.  Like 1.php?g=1 1.php?g=2 1.php?g=3 ... each url are diffrent number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already use SimpleSoftwareIO, just write:

```
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\BaconQrCodeGenerator;
```

and put this code in your loop:

```
$qrcode = new BaconQrCodeGenerator;
$qrcode->size(100)->generate("your text", 'path to save file');
```

It worked for me.